# How to use / run Matlab .m file in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, matlab, matlab-java

I have create `.m` file or `.mat` file i.e Matlab file and I am using Eclipse december 2017 version JDK 10 , what all are the steps to use these already created `.m` files / `.mat` files in Eclipse to run and get the output as it is giving my running `.m` files in Matlab software.
I want to know, how I can run my `.m` file (Matlab function files ) in Eclipse using Java?

Answer (score 1):

You should run your code by command line. So use a command line like this in a java command executor.

```
"C:\<matlab path>\matlab.exe" -nodisplay -nosplash -nodesktop -r "run('C:\<program path>\mfile.m');exit;"
```